# Qt5 (c++) android listening for system buttons

Tags: android, c++, qt, qevent

I want to use the menu button in my android app (4.x so usually software, not hardware buttons) but I can't find a suitable QEvent to do so. I tried to do

```
bool GLViewer::event(QEvent * e){
    qDebug()<<e->type();
}
```

But pressing the menu button had no output, I'm assuming because the menu button is outside the widget. How do I listen for this type of event?

Answer (score 1):

As read on this [post](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/29366), you can use the keyReleaseEvent() on your main window.